# How to open link with specific tab active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 3 php files content.php, functions.php and topics.php
I want that when a user clicks on an  link in topics.php that they get redirected to a page with tab1 open and that on the same link but at different button that tab2 is open when they click on the link.

I have tried code with onClick="" and with jquery but none of that has worked.

The active tab must reflect where on the site the user has clicked (i.e. whether the user clicked the first 'Algebra' link or the second one).

The  links are defined and created in topics.php

Comment: maybe in this function: onClick="selectTab("nav-y1")". Have you tried the id "navtab-y1" ( onClick="selectTab("navtab-y1"))

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it doesn't work as the id of the tab is: navtab-y1 but the href of the tab is: #nav-y1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own question:

In functions.php I added the code:

```
function wwp_custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'tab';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wwp_custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

And in the topics.php I added:

```
?var=variable1
```

To the url

and in content.php I added the conditions check by calling:

```
get_query_var('var');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do this, and it requires no JavaScript.  Use the [`:target` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

```
<div class="tab" id="tab1">
  <h1>This is Tab #1</h1>
</div>

<div class="tab" id="tab2">
  <h1>This is Tab #2</h1>
</div>
```

In your CSS, start with something like this:

```
.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Then, when you go to `page.html#tab1`, you'll see the first tab.  Or, `page.html#tab2`, you'll see the second.

This should you get you started.  You'll obviously want to set your CSS rules such that one of the tabs is showing by default, for when the page is shown without an anchor fragment.  And, you'll want to link to these anchor fragments from somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I already have my css rules so that one of the tabs is showing by default, it's the navtab-x1. How would I go about linking these anchor fragments from somewhere?

Comment: @LiamBartsch Just use `<a href="#tab2">Text here</a>`

Comment: Thank you for your help unfortunately what I want is to distinguish between when a user clicks on the link from a button and when the page loads normally. Therefore this doesn't work but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @LiamBartsch Yeah, that's not at all what your question says.  You said, "How to open link with specific tab active".  If what you actually want to ask is something completely different, you should just make a new question at this point.

Comment: No that is what I want to ask how to open link with specific tab active and the way I'm trying to go about it is by distinguishing between when a user clicks it and when it loads normally, it is not something completly different, there's no need to downvote my question as it is relevant.

Comment: @LiamBartsch What I'm telling you is that if you link to your page with the right anchor fragment, and if you use the `:target` CSS selector, the browser takes care of this for you on its own.  You can link to the page and have a specific tab active.  How is that not what you want?

Comment: I am terribly sorry I misunderstood and as I am new to the community and to the web development I thought you were talking about something else. I am very sorry, please forgive my misunderstanding thank you so much for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case to load a link with specific tab as active you utilize your URL Hash more:

If you have this link:

pockettutor.ie/algebra/#nav-y1

Then

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  if(window.location.hash) { // Check if url hash is not empty
      var hash = window.location.hash; // nav-y1
      document.querySelector('[href="'+hash+'"]').click();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your approach but it still doesn't work, should the ```if(window.location.hash)``` be inside a function maybe? I'm not 100% sure how the <script> works but don't you have to call the function and if there is no function then it doens't get called?

Comment: here i have checked your link

Comment: i also tested it and it worked out, it automatically clicked the button it needed to click

Comment: Thanks Jovylle but how do I call that script from the code:
<a href="https://www.pockettutor.ie/algebra#nav-y1" class="btn bg-secondary2 text-white w-100 text-left text-capitalize display-14">Algebra</a>

When I click on the link the page is fine but the tab I want open with Past Papers with Solutions (nav-y1) isn't open so it still doesn't work.

Comment: dont update the <a> tag, i am currently using this "<a class="nav-item nav-link text-black border rounded-top border-grey2 active" id="navtab-y1" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-y1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-y1" aria-selected="true">Past Papers With Solutions</a>"

Comment: I'm confused, maybe I should have been more clear:
I want that when a user presses the button called Algebra at this url with the tab "Past Papers by topic" selected: https://www.pockettutor.ie/maths
that the page : https://www.pockettutor.ie/algebra/#nav-y1 opens with the tab "Past Papers with Solutions" active but currently it's the other tab "Topics" that is open by default

Comment: when a user open this link "https://www.pockettutor.ie/algebra/#nav-y1" it should also view the "Past Papers With Solutions" part and not the "Topics" right? if it is, this answer will help, you.

Comment: is your problem where to write the code? or how to execute it?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it when a use opens the link pockettutor.ie/algebra/#nav-y1 it should view Past Papers with solutions and not the Topics part. and yes where do I write that code? because currently I have the code for the button on the maths page which is:

<a href="https://www.pockettutor.ie/algebra/#nav-y1" class="btn bg-secondary2 text-white w-100 text-left text-capitalize display-14">Algebra</a>

but where do I put the code that you gave me and how to execute it

Comment: Okay, programming sometimes gets really frustrating. but can i ask you this first.  Can you edit files from "www.pockettutor.ie" website? Because i am also confuse from where is that <a> going to show.

Comment: Yes I can I have admin access and have all the files, currently I am doing all my editing in a file called topics.php which I've notived affects the page: pockettutor.ie/maths

Comment: Okay very well, https://zerobacklog.com/swiftytools/uploads/pile_2020/2020-06-16_07:44:16_image.png
please see the image link.
you just need to add the script to the buttom of the 
<body>
</body> from that page.

Comment: We also assumed that the code in your question are made by you. and we assumed you know where to put them.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much so after the tag </body> I add :
<a class="nav-item nav-link text-black border rounded-top border-grey2 active" id="navtab-y1" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-y1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-y1" aria-selected="true">Past Papers With Solutions</a>
?

Comment: no, add this one: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  if(window.location.hash) { // Check if url hash is not empty
      var hash = window.location.hash; // nav-y1
      document.querySelector('[href="'+hash+'"]').click();
  }
</script>

Comment: I changed it so that it's a function but still doesn't seem to work:
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
  function changeTab(){
  if(window.location.hash) { // Check if url hash is not empty 
   var hash = window.location.hash; // nav-y1 
   document.querySelector('[href="'+hash+'"]').click(); }
  }
 </script>